# Add advanced search option for finding locked posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, locked

I was trying to look up some locked posts to check on because of the recent feature requests, and saw that there was no **islocked:1** option.

This would help complete the set of advanced search options.

Comment: I think this would be nice just to be complete, but the problem is that many locked posts don't *stay* locked - they're locked long enough for whatever controversy surrounded them to blow past, then unlocked.

Comment: @Shog9: Perhaps, but I think it's more than just completeness. I think there is validity to the suggestion, not for `locked:1`, but rather `locked:0` -- I may only be interested in searching for *unlocked* posts if I'm looking to answer something. This would also remove any migrated posts from the search.

Comment: @G.P.LeChuck: Good point on removing migrated posts, hadn't thought of that!

Comment: `closed:0` filters out the migrated posts. @gpl

Comment: +1 Tried to do this a couple days ago and realized it wasn't implemented.

Comment: `closed:0` doesn't apply if you're searching something like http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[not-programming-related]%20closed:1&page=1&tab=newest to delete and retag, where filtering out migrated (really, any locked, but most of those are migrated) questions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case that isn't implemented, for whatever reason, you can find out if a post has ever been locked by [using the following Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22Post+locked+by%22&aq=f&aql=&aqi=&oq=&cad=h):

```
site:stackoverflow.com "Post locked by" -migrated
```

Type that into Google.  The `-migrated` allows you to omit posts with the word 'migrated' in them (for those posts that are locked due to migration).

You can also try "`Locked By Jeff Atwood`" (or any of the moderator Names) to see ones that may slip through, but this should catch most of them.

Comment: I'd given you an upvote on this back when you first posted.  I'm mostly accepting it because you're so close to 10k, and I want to give you a shove closer to the line.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: As of right now, this page seems to be the only one returned by that search.

Comment: @pkaeding they may have changed the way they do that; I'll re-look.

Answer (score 7):

This got implemented a while back when we switched over to using Elasticsearch.

To search for locked posts, use `locked:1`.