# Please keep closed & locked posts from showing up in searches

Tags: feature-request, search, closed-questions, locked

Let's have search **not show** results with **closed & locked** posts in them.  Most of the material on locked posts are polls, or aren't relevant to current questions.  We will need to implement [locked searches as per this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36973/add-advanced-search-option-for-finding-locked-posts) if we do that though, so they can still be found if need be.

Note: Another motivation for this is so that old good (but no longer relevant) or poll posts don't have to be deleted, they can be locked, but the search results will still clean up.

Comment: I am all for this; let's keep the internet troll-free. In fact, I up-voted you 3 times.

Comment: (+1) although, I'd say closed **and** locked. Locked posts may still be worth seeing, but if they're closed and locked, it means that we pretty much want them in stasis.

Comment: I'm kinda ok with locked posts dropping out of search results completely... Sorta fits with the whole, "let this cool off" idea. Especially since locking now *implicitly closes* questions... @devinb

Comment: Along those lines it might be nice if closed/locked posts don't show up when you click on a tag.