# Mark locked questions [locked] in their titles

Tags: feature-request, title, locked

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we please get some UI differentiation for locked posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51498/could-we-please-get-some-ui-differentiation-for-locked-posts)

When browsing through question lists, it is impossible to identify locked questions without clicking through. I find this particularly annoying when coming across a merged question (they're "all" locked) as they have 0 answers. In the [particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551090/codegolf-find-the-unique-paths) that spurred this request, there were also 0 votes. Compare that to the [main copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551054/codegolf-find-the-unique-paths), which has 11 votes and 8 answers.

Could a string such as `[locked]` be tagged onto the end of the title to make it easier to ignore locked questions, as is done with closed questions?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36973/add-advanced-search-option-for-finding-locked-posts